# Select substring from a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I match a substring on another table?

Table 1:

```
Reference | Value
----------+-------
1         | 02.02.2011 07:07:00 498-123456-741
5         | 123-789654-100
5         | 123-789654-100
```

Table 2:

```
Reference | Code
----------+-------
5         | 123-789654-700
1         | 498-123456-100
```

I want to count the value from table one on table 2

```
select count(value) as count
from table 1 join table 2 on substring(value,0,12)=substring(code,0,12)
where reference='5'
```

If it the value is present in Table 2 it gives me a count of 2.

```
select count(value) as count
from table 1 join table 2 on substring(value,20,12)=substring(code,0,12)
where reference='1'
```

So the first query works fine the second query when a value comes in like  `02.02.2011 07:07:00 498-123456-741` it doesn't compare it to table to even though that value is there, in Table 2 it will always be a substring of (0,12).

Comment: Do a `REVERSE` and get the index of the first `' '`.

Comment: Is it a datetime column? if yes then use Datepart function to get values http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp

Comment: select count(value) as count from table 1 join table 2 on substring(value,20,10)=substring(code,0,10) where reference='1'.  this will work for 2nd query, but it is not way to do it. You are manually giving length and index of each substring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is like this : `SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )`

For example :

```
SELECT x = SUBSTRING('abcdef', 2, 3);
```

Here is the result set:

```
x
----------
bcd
```

You should do like this :

```
select count(*) as count from 
table 1 join table 2
on substring(value,20,12)=substring(code,0,12)
```

Comment: thats the same way i have it now,i tried the (*) its still doesnt give a result ,which it should work

Comment: your are using count(value), just use count(*) as count  or count(*) as value, it should work

Comment: i have to specify the column name cause i have multiple columns in that table

Comment: Count is keyword specifying number of records returned in select query, pleas tell me exactly your requirement

Comment: if i do the exact same query but have it as substring(value,0,12)=substring(code,0,12) with the respective data to go with it ,it works. but when a value comes in like this 02.02.2011 07:07:00 498-123456-741 and i do this substring(value,20,12)=substring(code,0,12) so that it matches on 498-123456 and give me a count of 1 it doesnt work

Comment: provide me your table structure. Is value column name? It is difficult to understand what exactly you need

Comment: Tell me, Does value change consistently, then how can you specify range like that.!

Comment: you are not calculating - in length. Also check for spaces , they also count.

Comment: i updated the question, hope its better to understand

Comment: It is because from 02.02.2011 07:07:00 498-123456-741, if you get 20 onwards index upto length of 12 that is : 498-123456-7 and then you compare it with 12 characters of 498-123456-100 that is 498-123456-1.
498-123456-7 is not equal to 498-123456-1

Comment: i thought that 20 would be the starting position for it to start from,cause i counted the spaces, if i perform just this select substring(value,20,12) from table 1 it gives this 498-123456- in return

Comment: select count(value) as count from table 1 join table 2 on substring(value,20,10)=substring(code,0,10) where reference='1'. this will work for 2nd query, but it is not way to do it. You are manually giving length and index of each substring.

Comment: What exactly is your requirement. Tell me , I will try to formulate query

Comment: samething i want to count the value that comes in but match it on the table 2 if its in table 2 then it must get counted,only table 2 has a fixed format  like this 498-123456-741 and table 1 comes in the 2 formats that i showed in  table 1, but the only thing is that you leave out the last 3 digits from both the tables

Comment: Do you need to do both in single query, both formats i mean

Comment: yep both in one query, i was trying to get it working in parts first, this is what i had select Count(value) from table 1 join table 2 on substring(value,0,12)=substring(code,0,12) OR substring(value,20,10)=substring(code,0,10) where code= (select top 1 code from table 2 where substring(value,0,12)=substring(code,0,12) OR substring(value,20,10)=substring(code,0,10))

Comment: so it would check both conditions and match it, but here it only matches with one condition where its substring(0,12)

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('w3resource', startingIndex, lengthForRequiredString);
```

**Example**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name, 4, 3);
```