# Vertica SQL - pull a specific value in a column,

Tags: sql, regex, string, select, vertica

beginner here with Vertical SQL.

There is a column called TEXT in our database. It has a bunch of information that I would like to parse that I do manually.

Example Below

```
TEXT
Age = 51, Country = USA, State = NY, .....
```

How would I do a subquery and search for specific string and pull that value? Meaning,

Select Text if it contains "Age" and the corresponding value?

Would really appreciate the help, have been parsing it in excel manually..

Thank you!

Comment: You should be storing those values in separate columns, especially if you are learning SQL.  Parsing strings is not what SQL is about.

Comment: Seems duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337908/select-substring-from-a-column-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Gordon Linoff, you should really fix your design, and store each value in a separate column rather than having a string in a single column that you need to parse.

In the meantime, one option is to use [regexp function `regexp_substr()`](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/RegularExpressions/REGEXP_SUBSTR.htm):

```
 regexp_substr(text, 'Age\s*=\s*(\S+)', 1, 1, '', 1)
```

`'Age\s*=\s*(\S+)'` means:

- litteral string '`Age'`
- 0 to n spaces
- a litteral `'='`
- 0 to n spaces
- as many characters as possible other than a space (at least 1)

The parentheses capture the last part, which you can then return using the last argument of the function (`1` means that the first captured group should be returned).

Answer (score 0):

If you need this often, write a function. 
And then use it to create a real table, where the "key" becomes the column name - and also a numeric string, like "51" becomes an INTEGER, not a VARCHAR...

Here's a function definition and a run test ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION val (
  s VARCHAR
, k VARCHAR
)
RETURN VARCHAR AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN REGEXP_SUBSTR(s,k||'\s*=\s*([^,]+),?',1,1,'i',1);
END;


WITH input(s,k) AS (
            SELECT 'Age = 51, Country = USA, State = NY','Age'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Age = 51, Country = USA, State = NY','Country'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Age = 51, Country = USA, State = NY','State'
)
SELECT
  *
, val(s,k)
FROM input;
                  s                  |    k    | val 
-------------------------------------+---------+-----
 Age = 51, Country = USA, State = NY | Age     | 51
 Age = 51, Country = USA, State = NY | Country | USA
 Age = 51, Country = USA, State = NY | State   | NY
```